# Best way to create a PDF with angular 2

Tags: angular, html2canvas, pdfmake, ngx-charts

what is the best way to create a pdf with angular 2?

I tried with pdfmake and html2canvas but I have some problems with rendering charts in IE (ngx-charts). So, do you think that another plugin is better?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to create a pdf with angular is to use (as you mentioned in your question) pdfmaker and html2canvas. What's the rendering problem you are talking about? Do you have a image you can post or an errormessage? 
If not, you could try to use jsPDF and see if that works for you.

Comment: Nah it was just a problem with the plugin ngx-chart. Html2canvas was not rendering charts on IE11. Now i used chartjs and it seems to work well